# var not updating after jQM call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working within jQuery Mobile.

When you hit Page1, I'm setting the ID of the page into a hidden input using PHP.

```
<input type="hidden" name="frmlid" id="frmlid" value="<?=$page_id;?>" />
```

When I click a button, it executes some jQuery which grabs the value of frmlid and alerts it out.  This works fine.

```
$(btnShowComments).bind('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var frmlid = $("#frmlid").val();
    alert(frmlid);
});
```

Now, lets say I navigate to Page2 from a link on Page1.  jQM does it's thing and loads up with whatever fancy ajax stuff it does.  Page2 does the same as Page1, sets the input value via PHP.

This time when btnShowComments is clicked, it alerts the previous page_id (Page1) and not Page2.

How can I get it to continually update when jQM loads up new pages?  If I right click and view source on Page2, the input's value is in fact Page2.  But it appears my jQuery code isn't updating/grabbing the new value.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

with jqm all pages are actually loading when you open the first page , so no matter what page you are in , all pages are loaded and rendered but it only shows the page that you are in  .

so first of all you can't(it's better not to) have a input with same id in all pages , instead use class .

and second assuming you have a button on every page with a hidden input close to it  , you have to get the nearest input to tuched button 
i.e the input in the same page as button

you can also find the parent div of the button and then find the input inside that div

```
<input type="hidden" name="frmlid" class="frmlid" value="<?=$page_id;?>" />
```

and jq code

```
$(btnShowComments).bind('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var frmlid = $(this).closest('.frmlid').val();
    alert(frmlid);
});
```

Comment: So if I have links to 100s of other files, it's actually loading all of those pages?  I'm linking to separate files, not just doing <div data-role="page" id="two" data-theme="a"> and <div data-role="page" id="three" data-theme="a"> all within one file.

Comment: no sorry i tough you'r just adding dive , in that case change hidden inoput to text input and make sure the value is right .

Comment: Yeah, that's the weird thing.  the ID in the input changes upon the new page being loaded, but frmlid actually stays the same as the previous page.

Comment: do the closest thing that i've said anyway , it should work .

Comment: No dice. It says undefined. But my input nor btnShowComments is not within a form -- could that be it?  I wrapped a form around it but no luck either.

Comment: trey wrapping both in a div , than on click get the parent element (wraper) and alert it's html to see whats inside you can use `$(wrapper).find` to get the input inside wrapper . ... also you can forget the input and store you data in a global javascript variable .

Comment: Ugh, thanks Max. I always seem to over-think the most simplistic things.  I put the id into a global js variable and it works great.